# One-sided version of the random oracle hypothesis

Tags: computational-complexity

The random oracle hypothesis states that relationships between complexity classes hold iff they hold relativized to a random oracle with probability 1. This is false, but all of the counterexamples I have seen are of the form $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{D}$ but $\mathcal{C}^A\neq\mathcal{D}^A$ (or $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{D}$ but $\mathcal{C}^A\nsubseteq\mathcal{D}^A$) for a random oracle $A$. Are there known (or suspected) counterexamples to the weaker conjecture that if $\mathcal{C}^A\subseteq\mathcal{D}^A$ with probability 1, then $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{D}$? If not, are there other reasons to believe or disbelieve this conjecture?

Of course, making this precise requires a definition of relativizable complexity class. https://www.research.ibm.com/people/b/bennetc/bennettc1981497f3f4a.pdf provides one possible axiomatization on page 110.

Comment: You are asking for relativizable classes $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}$ such that $\mathcal{C}^A \subseteq \mathcal{D}^A$ with probability 1 (over $A$), but $\mathcal{C} \not\subseteq \mathcal{D}$. The problem is, aside from the time & space hierarchy theorems (which relativize), and very low-level classes like $\mathsf{AC}^0$ or $\mathsf{ACC}$, we don't know many unconditional results of the form $\mathcal{C} \not\subseteq \mathcal{D}$

Comment: Good point. I'm still interested if there are strongly suspected counterexamples though, and there are plenty of widely believed noncontainments of complexity classes that couldn't relativize to all oracles.